# PHP detection of Fetch Api vs XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fetch

As of right now my site is using jQuery Ajax to make a request from front end to back end and then the backend determines the ajax request by checking for $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest". I'm trying to switch over to native JS only, and want to use the Fetch Api. Problem is I can't seem to detect the fetch api request in PHP vs regular page load request. $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] obviously doesn't work anymore. So I tried to set new Header({HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH}). Then it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated, Thanks

JS:

```
let dataForm = new FormData(),
    reqHeaders = new Headers({
      "X-Custom-Header": "ThisMeansAjaxRequest",
    });

  dataForm.append('postFavColor', 'green');

  let result = fetch('/ajax/', {
    method: 'POST',
    header: reqHeaders,
    body: dataForm
  })
  .then(res=>{
    if('json' in res){
      return res.json()
    }
    throw new Error('Not so JSON');
  })
  .then(res=>{
    if (res.status === 'success') {
      // WE MADE IT!!!
      console.log(req);
      return res.message
    }
    else{
      throw new Error('Server returned Error', res)
    }
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    console.error('fetch error of some sort', err);
  });
```

PHP:

```
    // Below if statment was being used for Ajax request test from jQuery
// replacing the if statement below with the custom header passed from fetch api
// still doesn't work. Tried all 4 versions below
// if (isset($_SERVER['X_Custom_Header']) && $_SERVER['X_Custom_Header']=="ThisMeansAjaxRequest")
// if (isset($_SERVER['Custom_Header']) && $_SERVER['Custom_Header']=="ThisMeansAjaxRequest")
// if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_Custom_Header']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_Custom_Header']=="ThisMeansAjaxRequest")
// if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_Custom_Header']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_Custom_Header']=="ThisMeansAjaxRequest")


//// Original jquery Ajax detector
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']=="XMLHttpRequest") {
        //continue;
        //echo 'This is certified Ajax request <br>';
    $data = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'You\'re a Wizzard Harry!'
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
}
        else{
    //Not ajax request so display page
        header("location: www.example.com/index.php");
}
```

Comment: Typo: it should be `headers:`, not `header:`.

Comment: @Barmar That' was a typo when I was rewriting this question. That and console.log(req), but the problem still stands. How will i detect it in PHP?

Comment: I performed a test of my own. When I corrected the typo, my PHP application was able to read `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_CUSTOM_HEADER']`.

Comment: Well then that's embarasing. I had the spelling right, but I had mine in lower case like so "HTTP_X_Custom_Header"  vs yours "HTTP_X_CUSTOM_HEADER". Thanks bro, greatly appreciate it. I wasted 5 hours on this