# How make redirection with web service?

Tags: php, json, url

I have a web-service which send JSON object as response to log my user.
But if I take the URL of the service and I put it on my navigator I see the json object, how I can send the json througth a redirection ?

Example : 
Facebook login -> if we take the action in the form that call facebook/login?...
If facebook use JSON to send a response of the log i must see the JSON object if i call facebook/login?... but I was redirected to the main page, how that works ?

Thank for your reply.

Comment: You need to handle response from your web-service with Javascript.

Comment: How ? with ajax ? I do this to get data in my page when the form is send, but how make redirection if the user put the form URL in the navigator ?

Comment: do you use JS framework? Or plain javascript? Most of the frameworks send additional header `'X-Requested-With'` for AJAX, so, in most cases you may simply check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` is isset on backend. Not very good, but simple solution.

But if you use vanilla JS, you can add it manually.

Comment: So, in your login handler, just check if this header is set. If yes - return JSON object, if not — redirect this request to any page you find suitable

Comment: I use vanilla JS. Can you tell me how $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] works in this case ?
I see your last message :
I must send an header from my AJAX request to my page ?

Comment: As for vaniila JS. Let's suppose you have `xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`. So, after `xmlhttp.open('GET', URL, true);` (yes, login through GET request is not a good idea, but this is just the example). And after `open`, you need to write the following `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');`

Comment: I you need more informations for AJAX request I use the new fetch API :
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch

Comment: Well, as far as I understood, fetchAPI has `Headers` interface. So, I think that you'll find useful these links: 1) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers 2)https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_your_own_request_object

Comment: Then I create an header like : headers: {
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
?
After I check my $_server[http_x_request].. on my backend an redirect if not same header ?

Comment: I think i found the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708042/php-detection-of-fetch-api-vs-xmlhttprequest
Thank for your help I did not know we can check if a request comes from ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to check the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] after sending an specific header in the AJAX request.

I have a last question in like :
Can i use a same like this the volley library, to allow the access to a php script only for an android app ?
You can see an example on header in this link :

https://gist.github.com/FabrizioCaldarelli/ad1118e5d8ab0661ba36